# CouchDB 2.1.0 does not work with windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, couchdb, windows-10-desktop, couchdb-2.0

I tried to install couchDB on windows 10.
now I know that there was a problem with couchDB and windows 10 creator update, 
but the problem was supposed to be fixed in version 2.1.0 like they said in the apache issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-3395.

I searched everywhere and all the answers refer to CouchDB 2.0.0 with windows 10 creator update, but I tried it anyway.

- switched the nssm to version 2.24
- tried to run from the cmd
- run it manually from the event viewer
- even reinstall and restart the computer

but nothing worked.

[image: I got this problem when Im trieng to run the couchDB manually from the services]

I got this problem when Im trieng to run the couchDB manually from the services.

and when I go to the event viewer this is the error:
[image: when i go to the event viewer this is the error]

I'm really clueless! 
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall? The couchdb.cmd file should be in the /bin folder.

Comment: I've reinstalled 3 times it didnt work and i didnt got the second question the couchdb.cmd is in the bin folder

Comment: If you run couchdb.cmd as Administrator does it works?

Comment: No unfortunately it does not work either way